# It's there any overhead while using Eureka and Zookeper(Kafka) in a JHipster Microservices environment?

Tags: apache-kafka, jhipster, apache-zookeeper, netflix-eureka, jhipster-registry

I'm actually building an microsysteme environment based on JHipster. But we have some questions about server overhead. 
JHipster Registry used per default Eureka and we want to add a Kafka as queue. The point is: Kafka come with Zookeeper embedded.
So Zookeeper and Eureka have good points when it's come to Service Discovery.

Should i replace the default Eureka (Jhipster-registry) by Zookeeper? so that i just run one Zookeeper for Discovery and Kafka.

Or should it will be no performance issues when i use the default setup? I will then need to start Eureka, Zookeeper and Kafka.

Comment: have u setup a kafka cluster? Kafka uses Zookeeper for co-ordination purposes,controller election,detecting when a new node joins or existing node leaves etc.As for using eureka, it depends on what u want to do. 
Could u elaborate on it.

Comment: @IndraneelBende the question is, if it's better to replace Eureka into Jhipster-registry with Zookeeper, to keep the whole systeme uniform. We plan to use Kafka+zookeeper anyway.

Comment: Yes, you can achieve the same thing with zookeeper , that u can do with eureka. Are u going to use other Netflix oss components like Zuul,ribbon etc?

Comment: Could u elaborate how ur going to use eureka?

Comment: We are using both eureka and zookeeper in production. If ur really low on resources, where u can’t deploy an eureka server, then u can go ahead with reusing zookeeper , other than that, there is no ‘overhead’ as such.

Comment: If ur going to use Zuul, ribbon etc , then use eureka, as these components know each other very well, I believe u could use zookeeper instead, but that will involve some research and require u to invest some time.

Comment: https://stackshare.io/stackups/consul-vs-eureka-vs-zookeeper
A link that u might find useful